# windows 10 - Disk Defragmentor Drive list

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, virtual-disk

I do not know if this is possile, but what I would like to do is manually exclude a partition from the list inside the 'Disk Defragmentor'.

[My Disk Defragmentor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIlO6.png)

The 'E:' drive is effectively a spanned Partition that is load balanced for space across multipe drives.
-Via stablebit Drivepool

Windows sees it as a phsyical HDD, is there any way i am able to hide it from that menu. (I do not want to cause undo stress on the Pool, when windows attempts to defrage a viruta/meta partition that in it self can never get fragmented or even find out if it loses it's mind over it)
-I also don't want to run the risk of it re-enabling it on the schedule as well.

Comment: I wouldn't use any software by Piriform is owned by Avast, and they have allowed their software to be infected with Malware.   As for manually excluding a partition, there is a **Change Settings**, which will allow you to change the schedule for a volume.

Comment: i know about the 'change setting' which thankfully easy to spot.  I am looking for a way to mask it.
--
I already changed the scedule.. I just rather not risk being to out of it, or windows changing it's mind about my settings [which can happen from time to time]